# Can "another" be preceded by "what" as in "What another factor will affect the rollout of the product?"

Tags: pronouns, questions, grammaticality-in-context, determiners, collocations

I've recently seen this question in an English textbook.

> (One of the only two factors is........) What **another** factor will affect the rollout of the product?

This struck me as awkwardly sounding because I've heard the question "What **other** choice do I have?" before, but not this.

So can "another" be preceded by "what" in this case? Should "other" be used here instead?

Pardon the example for being too specific. This problem wasn't very Googleable.

Comment: I would post this on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @fev It's on-topic here and the author may not want an answer couched in linguistic terms.

Comment: @ColleenV Fair enough. Not saying it's off-topic here. Just that the answer is not so straightforward...

Comment: @fev There are plenty of questions on ELL where the answer is not straightforward. I don't understand why you think that makes them a better candidate for ELU. The difference in the two sites is not about how easy a question is to answer.

Comment: @ColleenV Could you elaborate on why the answer isn't straightforward? I posted this question here precisely because I thought it should've been straightforward and not worthy of an ELL treatment.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw I wasn't the one who stated it wasn't straight-forward. You should choose between ELU and ELL based on what type of answer you would like, not how difficult or not difficult you guess the answer to your question might be. If you want a practical "I'm learning English and want to know how to use this" answer, that's more likely what you will get on ELL. If you want a more linguistics-oriented answer that may have technical terms or delve into etymology, then choose ELU.

Comment: Sorry to have raised the question of ELU. The answer is clearly _What other factor_, but when I tried to find a resource that explains _**why**_, I realised that it is indeed not so straightforward to find ... And since on ELU they are more strict with reliable resources... It is indeed an interesting question and will definitely upvote it.

Comment: @ColleenV sorry for the misdirected reply. I had no intention of finding out what is the true logic behind how the word "another" doesn't pair well with "what", or anything beyond surface-level grammaticality. I think I made the right call posting here, given that I'm still very much in the process of learning (everybody is, isn't they?)

Comment: (For the record, it is easy for a native speaker to tell you which one is right... much harder to say why one is right and the other isn't. I may give it a shot though :))

Comment: The idiomatic way to ask that question would be "What other factors might affect the rollout of the product?". Specifying only one factor is unnaturally presumptive (i.e. the speaker would be assuming that there is only _one_ factor). 'Will' is technically correct, but 'might' is better because it admits that none of us can be certain about the future. I'm not sure why 'another' is wrong. I suspect it's likely an incompatibility with 'what', because "Is there another factor that could affect the product launch?" would be perfectly fine (though "any other factor" would be more natural).

Comment: @Pharap in the original context, there are only two factors. One has already been mentioned, so the question asks the reader to state the other. Whatever the original context, the point is the noun in question is singular, which I agree isn't very typical in this kind of collocation, but still occurs regardless. I edited my question for clarity.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw In that case, it would be much more likely that the response would just be "What other factor?" because the context is likely to be known. (That extra verbosity might be causing some users confusion.) But either way, plurality doesn't affect the scenario at all. Whether it's one factor or ten, 'another' is still incorrect. (If the question was "Would you like another biscuit?" then you'd have to ask "Would you like another three biscuits?" (number specified) or "Would you like some more biscuits?" (number unspecified), but that's a different matter entirely.)

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw  You're simply looking for **is**, because it's singular.  "What is another factor .."  "What is another solution .."  "What is the solution .." "What is the best highway .." and so on.  It's that simple.  Your whole sentence would be "What **is** another factor which **would** affect the rollout .."

Comment: @Fattie sorry but that's not what I'm looking for. It's not really a matter of massaging the question and making it nicer sounding, but a matter of the grammaticality of this specific kind of question.

Answer (score 8):

I think this has to do with "another" as a determiner referring to something more specific and "other" as a determiner referring to something more general, similar to the usage of "the" versus "a".

If you look at the [etymology of another](https://www.etymonline.com/word/another) it is a merger of "an" + "other".

> "not this, not the same; someone or something else," early 13c., merger of an + other. Old English used simply oþer. Originally "a second of two." Compound reciprocal pronoun one another is recorded from 1520s.

From Longman:

> [Another](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/another)  :
> 1 ADDITIONAL **one more** person or thing of the same type
> *I’m going to have another cup of coffee.*
> 2 A DIFFERENT ONE not the same thing, person etc, but **a different one**
> *They must have returned by another route.*

> [Other](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/other) :
> 3 ADDITIONAL used to refer to **additional people or things** of the same kind
> *There are one or two other problems I’d like to discuss.*
> 4 DIFFERENT used to refer to **a different person or thing** from the one you have already mentioned or the one that is already known about
> *Do you envy other women who seem to manage their lives better?*

Compare:

1. <sup>ok</sup>What other factor will affect the rollout?
2. <sup>∗</sup>What **the** other factor will affect the rollout?
3. <sup>∗</sup>What another factor will affect the rollout?
4. <sup>ok</sup>What **is the other** factor **that** will affect the rollout?
5. <sup>ok</sup>What **is another** factor **that** will affect the rollout?

The determiner "another" already has the specificity of an article "built in".  We wouldn't write "The another reason I have." but we could write "The other reason I have."

Comment: The problem with "what ANother" definitely lies in the presence of this indefinite article AN... "What" is a predeterminer which CAN be combined with other determiners, but strangely enough, not with "another".  And what is bugging me, is that when I first read "what another" and had the certitude it is incorrect, I knew that the reason was grammatical;  not because its "not idiomatic" character...

Comment: @fev: Offhand, I can't think of any situation where the *interrogative* sense of "what" can be combined with another determiner; we can say "What a country that is!", but not \*"What a country is that?" (Unless you're thinking of something like "What three countries [...]?"; but numerals are a special case, in that they appear after many determiners that don't otherwise precede determiners, as in "the three countries", "these three countries", "which three countries", "my three countries", etc.)

Answer (score 2):

OK, this is a really strange way of answering, but maybe it has something to do with substituting "another" with "one". Let's see these examples which are valid with "another":

> Would you like another (one) cup of coffee?

> You’ve met Linda, but I have another (one) sister who you haven’t met, called Margaret.

> I don’t like this place. Is there another (one) café around here we could go to? (alternative or different)

*Examples taken from [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/other-others-the-other-or-another)*

All examples after substituting are still grammatically correct. However:

> What another (one) factor will affect the rollout of the product?

Substituting "one" seems to work here, but why doesn't it work with "another"? This seems to be "another"s anomaly. One reason why the sentence works above seems to be the change in type of determiner.

[Etymology of "another"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/another)

> early 13c., merger of an + other

This shows how "an"+"other" was used. "an" is an article. We don't usually put an article with a number determiner, as number's usually are in front of a noun.

Comment: _"Another" as a determiner usually requires a verb/adverb in front of it_. Really? Where did you find this rule?

Comment: Isn't "other" the plural of "another"? I believe you should say "what other factors?", not "what other factor"?

Comment: I liked the verb answer until I realised "Did another man come by here after I left?" is perfectly valid and the verb comes after rather than before, just as in the OP's example. Perhaps there's something in the difference between 'did' and 'what'? That one asks for information about an action, and the other asks about an object?

Comment: @fev Sorry, I completely changed my answer now

Comment: @JohnDouma no. Both are singular. "Another" tends to emphasize the *additional* nature of something, like "there is another cupcake remaining."  "An other" tends to emphasize the *different* nature of something: "the other cupcake is chocolate".

Comment: @fectin "An other" is never correct. See [this](https://www.englishcurrent.com/grammar/other-another-difference/). I phrased my comment as a question but it was rhetorical.

Comment: @JohnDouma try this: "Society conditions us to ostracize the other; to regard him as anathema. When you find yourself regarded as an other, it is a cold feeling."

Comment: @fectin That is incorrect. It shoud be: "ostracize another" and "regarded as another".

Comment: @JohnDouma,fectin:  I do think that "the other" and "an other" are correct in that context.  This is a relatively contemporary usage of "other" as a noun rather than as an adjective/determiner.  It means (OED) "a person other than oneself; a person or group that is outside or excluded from one's own group."  There are several usage examples along these lines in the OED, if you want backup on that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a theory that I don't have any supporting evidence for, but as it seems to fit I'm going to propose it regardless.

After looking at [English Determiners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners), it seems to me that in the question "What another factor (will affect the rollout of the product)?", the 'what' is actually an *interrogative determiner*, thus placing 'another' directly after it means you end up with two determiners in a row. I haven't found a resource saying that this is incorrect, but I believe it likely is incorrect. From a few attempts, placing an interrogative determiner in front of some other determiner seems to always produce incorrect sentences, which I am presuming is *because* of the two determiners being used one after another.

In contrast, in the correct sentence "What other factor(s) (will affect the rollout of the product)?" the interrogative determiner is followed by a noun ('factor(s)') that has been modified by an adjective ('other'), which follows the grammatical pattern for an interrogative determiner.

See the examples [here](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/determiners-interrogative.htm). E.g. "What books did you read?", "Which red pen do you want?" - the interrogative determiner is always followed by some noun, possibly modified with an adjective. That appears to be the pattern.

Comment: I edited my question. "Factor" must necessarily stay singular, which is likely why whoever came up with the question made this potential error in the first place.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw That doesn't change my answer. Plurality doesn't affect the grammar in this instance. I will add brackets for your convinience though.

Comment: I think you’re on to something with “other” being an adjective and another being a determiner. We can say “Some other factor” but not “Some another factor”.

Comment: both what and other are determiners.

Comment: @fev "Other" is not a determiner. "Other" can perfectly well modify a noun which is also modified by a determiner, for example "my other issue" or "the other factor".

Comment: @fev 'Other' [_can_ be a determiner](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/other#Determiner), but it [can also be an adjective](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/other#Adjective). 'What' can be [a determiner](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what#Determiner), [a pronoun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what#Pronoun), [an adverb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what#Adverb), and rarely [a noun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what#Noun). 'Another' can only be [a determiner](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/another#Determiner) or [a pronoun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/another#Pronoun). Context matters.

Answer (score 0):

I think another possible reason the answer is no might be that we could say

> What an important factor that is!

or

> What a different experience that was!

So, if we could say, “*what another factor,” it would sound like “what an other factor.”  That sounds like an exclamation of how *other* the factor is.  But *other* doesn’t take a degree.  We can’t say, “more other” or “most other,” either.

Comment: I did raise some cases where what could comfortably precede another. "You can see what another person can see." "What another lovely day at the Four Seasons Hotel." But none of these have anything to do with this particular case, but rather, with relative clauses and exclamations.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw The original question doesn’t have a relative clause, though. I suspect the similarity to this construct might be why the other usage never caught on.

Answer (score 0):

No, the sentence is not correct. In that sentence, "what" is a determiner, but "another" is also a determiner, and a noun can never have two determiners.

Comment: Pretty slick answer, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

However, I would jus like to help clarify some things:

1. There is no doubt that **What another factor will affect the rollout?* is UNGRAMMATICAL. If you see it used, know it's a mistake. Be also aware though, that persistent mistakes could one day become a rule and accepted by all.
2. In your examples, ***what, other*** and ***another*** are ALL determiners. We do not speak of the use of ***other*** as an *adjective* here (by the way, ***another*** *[cannot be used as an adjective](https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-another-and-other.html#:%7E:text=Key%20Differences%20Between%20Another%20and%20Other&text=Another%20is%20mainly%20used%20with,a%20determiner%2C%20pronoun%20and%20adjective.)*. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/another) and [OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=another&sxsrf=ALiCzsbraE-Jh027LtGRv8OGmvKoTjAWIA%3A1659777198195&ei=rjDuYtfDC_iBhbIP0u-LyAw&oq=&gs_lcp=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&sclient=gws-wiz) seem to agree with that). And so that we are clear about the use of *other* as an adjective, here is an example:

> There was a fear that under the costume there is something foreign, something terrifying and *essentially* ***other***. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/other))

3. Let's also "demystify" the fact that ***another*** CAN be used with plural nouns in combination with a word of quantity:

> The sim card is valid for ***another*** *five* ***years***.

4. I don't know where people read that nouns can only take one determiner. I am afraid that's not true, and this is one of the aspects which created confusion in "deciphering" this structure:

> *Some determiners function as "pre-determiners" — they can come BEFORE a main determiner.* You can have ONE pre-determiner:
>
> - ***all*** ***the*** right people / ***half my*** weight ([source](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/determiners-order.htm)).

---

Now that all this is out of the way, let's get to the point. Why do ***what*** and ***another*** exclude each other?

As others have shown, determiners can be specifying (*the, this*) and non-specifying (*a, another*). We all agree that you cannot have two determiners both ***singling out** the noun*<sup>1</sup> next to each other. You cannot say **the a man*, but either ***a man*** or ***the man***. A noun can be ***singled out*** only once, whether definitely or indefinitely.

Now, ***what*** definitely ***specifies*** and ***singles out*** the noun:

> determiner
> Used for asking for information ***specifying*** something. ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=what&sxsrf=ALiCzsazVNRzB6YZj2yQglhyjnnXHtRgIg%3A1659785931521&source=hp&ei=y1LuYqa9HZeDhbIPocC-0AM&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYu5g23IYP1L1tdVUsyden29aAzBdB4yB&ved=0ahUKEwjmzuW2kLL5AhWXQUEAHSGgDzoQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=what&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgjECcyBAgjECcyBAgjECcyBAgAEEMyBQgAEJECMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgQIABBDOgoIABCxAxCDARBDUABYrgNg_whoAHAAeACAAagBiAHBA5IBAzIuMpgBAKABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz))

Whereas ***an**other* is ***non-specific***, due to the built-in indefinite article:

> We use ‘another’ when we are talking about singular ***non-specific*** countable nouns ([source](https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-another-and-other.html#:%7E:text=Key%20Differences%20Between%20Another%20and%20Other&text=Another%20is%20mainly%20used%20with,a%20determiner%2C%20pronoun%20and%20adjective.)).

but it DOES ***single out*** the noun: ANother = ***ONE** other*.

THEREFORE, although I have not been able to find this written anywhere, I do believe that ***what*** and ***another*** exclude each other in the same way ***the*** and ***a*** do.

***What*** already singles out ***factor***, so we can only combine it with with another determiner that is as indefinite as it gets, a determiner that does NOT single out (like ***other***).

You will see the same happening with other main determiners:

> **This another*, **My another*

will never work for the same reason.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I don't know what else to call it, sorry if the terminology is not right. Once I name a noun using a determiner, definite or indefinite, it is differentiated ( or *singled out*) from the rest of the items from the same class.</sub>

Comment: Very interesting. I wonder if there's a common term for "the kind of determiner that a noun phrase can only have one of" (if that's even a meaningful concept at all).

Comment: five years is not a plural noun, it's entirely singular

Comment: @Fattie At least [notionally](https://www.mmmenglish.com/2019/08/02/use-other-or-another-correctly/#:~:text='Another'%20can%20be%20used%20with,is%20plural%20and%20it's%20countable.) it is plural. _**Another few ideas** came into his mind just now._